# how to view all deployments with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a desktop application that runs a docker-compose deployment for a distributed system in the background and acts as a fancy UI for it.

I can see the docker containers with `docker ps` and inspect them as you normally would be able to, however I can't seem to view it with `docker-compoes ps` or have docker-compose acknowledge it in any way.

How can I interact with this deployment, when I don't know where the docker-compose.yaml is on disk?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get docker-compose.yml file location from running container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108163/get-docker-compose-yml-file-location-from-running-container)

Comment: This did not work for me, however if the only way forward is to somehow find the docker-compose file because the behavior I'm asking for is impossible, you should provide that as an answer